# Number of objects created during string concatenation

Tags: java, string, object

Can someone please tell me how many objects will be created on executing the `System.out.println` statement in the below code

```
int i=0;
int j=1;
System.out.print("i value is "+ i + "j value is "+j);
```

Comment: It is implementation dependent - probably 5 on hotspot... Why does it matter?

Comment: I can see only 1 String object created here. See my answer. If anyone thinks something else, please provide an explanation rather than saying random numbers.

Comment: this questions is not clear on if compile time created objects should also be considered or not; all provided answers at the moment leave those out. On compile time there are 4 allocations, 2 inherit from Object (both Strings)

Comment: I agree with @assylias. This doesn't appear to be particularly important. I don't think knowing this detail makes one a better java developer

Answer (score 7):

If you really want to know what's going on, why not look at the bytecode?

I wrapped your code in a main function, compiled it and then disassembled it with `javap -c Test.class`. Here's the output (using a Oracle Java 7 compiler):

```
Compiled from "Test.java"
class Test {
  Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: iconst_0
       1: istore_1
       2: iconst_1
       3: istore_2
       4: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       7: new           #3                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
      10: dup
      11: invokespecial #4                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
      14: ldc           #5                  // String i value is
      16: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      19: iload_1
      20: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      23: ldc           #8                  // String j value is
      25: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      28: iload_2
      29: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      32: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      35: invokevirtual #10                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.print:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      38: return
}
```

The only object that gets allocated *in this method* is the `StringBuilder` (by the `new` instruction at position 7). However, the other methods that are `invoke`d might allocated something themselves, and I have a very strong suspicion that StringBuilder.toString will allocate a `String` object.

Comment: The comments in the code suggest that only one StringBuilder object is created then all other given arguments for the + operator are appended to the StringBuilder object and at the end the toString() method is called from the StringBuilder object,and the returned String value is passed to the print() method.

Answer (score 4):

This will create a `StringBuilder` object (and whatever this object uses internally), add the values and finally the `StringBuilder` will create a `String` object with the result.

Answer (score 2):

The code

```
int i=0;
int j=1;
System.out.print("i value is "+ i + "j value is "+j);
```

*Creates 3 objects.*

**My Reason:**

The basic data types in Java are not objects and does not inherit from Object. so 
 `int i=0; and int j=1;` does not make an object.

Now `System.out.print("i value is "+ i + "j value is "+j);` which contains `String` which are immutable, and the operations on string are costly.We can split the operations as this.

```
("i value is ").concat(i)  // creates one object let say obj1
obj1.concat("j value is ")   //creates another let say obj2
obj2.concat(j)            // creates the final string let say obj3;
```

In an example string operation `str1.concat(str2)` is done by using two String objects and it creates the third one and change the reference making an illusion that its actually the first string object ie str1. Thus the str1 will be having a new String which contains the value of the old str1 and the str2 concatenated.

*This is what i believe with my limited knowledge. Correct me if i am wrong.*

Comment: I would argue that `("i value is").concat(i)` makes 2 objects. First it has to make "i value is". Then it has to `concat` i to it to return a new string.

Comment: It's `obj1="i value is";obj2=obj1.concat(i);obj3="j value is";obj4=obj2.concat(obj3);obj5=obj4.concat(j);`

Comment: `"i value is"` will already be in existence before the statement runs.

Comment: @Cruncher I have looked for that, but i haven't found any valid documentations for that. I believe that the `("i value is").concat(i)` consider `i value is` as an input rather than an object. Do you have any valid documentation to support your argument.?

Comment: @cHao Are you saying that an object is created for `"i value is"` before the `concat` operation is done.? Do you have any supporting document, i like to learn what's going on inside .!!

Answer (score 1):

Only `1`, the String object get concatenated.

Answer (score 1):

If it is indeed implementation dependent, then if it is evaluated to:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("i value is ");
sb.append(i);
sb.append(j);
String newStr = sb.toString();
```

There will be 2 objects.

Comment: I see at least two here!

Comment: So **during** concatenation it will actually be **two** objects, right? `StringBuilder` and `String`

Comment: Commenters, please suggest a *correction* instead of saying: **THAT'S WRONG**.

Comment: "i value is" is one. StringBuilder#append may create additional strings + the final one.

Comment: Do we care about the objects being created by the StringBuilder?  There's a backing store of some kind (probably an array, i haven't looked), which may be resized over the course of the operation.

Answer (score 1):

The code is converted, by the compiler, to something like this:

```
int i=0;
int j=1;
StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(); // creates a StringBuilder
temp.append("i value is "); // creates or re-uses a String
temp.append(i); // might create a String
temp.append("j value is"); // creates or re-uses a String
temp.append(j); // might create a String
String temp2 = temp.toString(); // creates a String
System.out.print(temp2);
```

It depends on whether you count the "i value is " and "j value is " strings, which are created once and then re-used.

If you do count them, then at least 4, otherwise at least 2.

Actually, each String has its own char[] that actually stores the string. So that's 7 or 3, instead of 4 or 2.

StringBuilder has a char[] as well and might have to create new char[]'s as you add more data to it. String.valueOf or System.out.print might also create objects behind your back *and there's no way you can know about them* without external tools. Hence "at least".

Comment: Are you sure about the `temp.append(String.valueOf(i))`? Since there is an `append` variant taking an `int` argument I would assume this is used.

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ This is not conclusive. The characters of the string representation could be determined and added individually without creating a `String`. Just the overall effect is the same.

Comment: Just tested it, it does call `temp.append(i)`. Edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Only 1 i.e  for printing the String .

**Thumb rule** - Whenever concatenation of strings are done , a new object is created.

Answer (score 0):

String is immutable means that you cannot change the object itself. 
While performing concatenation every time new string objects are created.
So in above example

1. int i
2. int j
3. "i value is "
4. "i value is "+ i
5. "i value is "+ i + "j value is "
6. "i value is "+ i + "j value is "+j

Total six objects are created in above example.

Comment: `int` is a primitive type, not an object. `Integer` on the other hand is.

Comment: @xlm so it depends on if during concatenation, the primitive is ever converted to an Integer. I doubt that to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

5 objects

1. "i value is ".A String object will be formed.
2. "i value is "**+i**.This concatenation operation will form 2nd Object.
3. "j value is " will form third object.
4. "i value is "+i **+** "j value is ".4th object formed because of concatenation.
5. "i value is "+ i + "j value is " **+** j .This last concatenation will form 5th object.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider 2 points here:

1. When you say String is immutable, it will create a new object if you try to change the value.
2. String object will be created when you write code using Literal(String s = "Pool") way or using new keyword (String s = new String("Heap and Pool"), here new keyword refers heap, the Literal "Heap and Pool" refers String constant pool).

In this case the above answer is correct. Five String objects will be created.