# Counting String objects created by Java code

Tags: java, string

How many String objects are created by the following code?

```
String x = new String("xyz");
String y = "abc";
x = x + y;
```

I have visited many websites where some say that this line of code creates 3 objects and some say it creates 4. I just wanted to know how many objects are created after this line of code is executed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Questions about Java's String pool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881922/questions-about-javas-string-pool)

Comment: Take a look through the 1.070.000 search results first and clarify how your question differs from them: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=java+how+many+string+objects+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: No that's not a good duplicate. The reassignment of reference `x` adds an important consideration here.

Comment: The reassignment makes no difference.  It is the expression that makes the difference

Comment: *"So this bounty is an attempt to get an answer that can clarify this with proper references. Please take into account any changes in Java 8 that may prove that the answers present are lacking in some details."*  1)  The accepted answer is 100% correct.  If you accept that it is correct, no further clarification is required.  If you don't "believe" it, then clarification won't help.  The answers that just give a number are incorrect.  If you want us to (magically) make all answers say the same thing ... your are dreaming, sunshine.

Comment: 2)  No changes in Java 8 change the correctness answer, or require clarification.  The only thing that changes in Java 8 is that the string pool doesn't live in permgen because permgen no longer exists.  But the accepted answer doesn't mention permgen.  (It is only mentioned in a couple of tangential comments about pemgen GC that are only of (ancient) historical interest.)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

By the end of the run there will be four `String` objects:

1. A `String` that corresponds to the interned `"xyz"` literal
2. Its copy created by `new String("xyz")`
3. A `String` that corresponds to the interned `"abc"` literal
4. A `String` that corresponds to concatenation `"xyz" + "abc"`

The real question is *attributing* some or all of these objects to your program. One can reasonably claim that as few as two or as many as four `String`s are created by your code. Even though there are four `String` objects in total, objects 1 and 3 may not necessarily be created by your code, because they are in a constant pool, so they get created outside your code's direct control.

Comment: after the lines are executed the 1. and 2. are ready for being garbage collected.

Actually right after the String constructor finishes there is no pointer to the original "xyz" literal

Comment: *"String object 4 can be computed by the compiler and turned into an interned constant as well"* - Not correct.  The expression is not a compile-time constant expression according to the JLS rules.

Comment: @xuma202 Literals are a special case, as there must be some form of reference from the defining class to the literal. Depending on the actual VM implementation they may even *never* be garbage collected (permanent generation in older Hotspot VMs).

Comment: @Durandal - really, really old Hotspot VMs.  Permgen GC was certainly implemented by Java 5.0.

Comment: Is there any way to count how many objects are created by string literal and String object ?

Answer (score 17):

This Answer is to correct a misconception that is being put about by some of the other Answers:

For example:

> The compiler might substitute x + y with a constant ("xyzabc"), though. @Binkan Salaryman
>
> ... and String object 4 [the String that corresponds to concatenation] can be computed by the compiler and turned into an interned constant as well. @dasblinkenlight

This is incorrect.  The [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1) states this:

> ### 15.18.1. String Concatenation Operator +
>
> ....
>
> The String object is newly created (§12.5) unless the expression is a constant expression (§15.28).

In order to qualify as a constant expression, the variable names in the expression must be:

> Simple names (§6.5.6.1) that refer to constant variables (§4.12.4).

where a "constant variable" is defined as:

> A constant variable is a final variable of primitive type or type String that is initialized with a constant expression (§15.28).

In this example, neither `x` or `y` are `final` so they are not constant variables.  And even if they were `final`, `y` *still* wouldn't be a constant variable because of the use of the `new` operator in its initialization.

---

In short, the Java compiler is *not permitted* to use an intern'd constant `"xyzabc"` as the result of the concatenation expression.

If I added the following statement at the end:

```
    System.out.println(x == "xyzabc");
```

it will always print `false` ... assuming that the compiler is conformant to the Java Language Specification.

Comment: It is entirely possible within the rules though for the JIT compiler to decide not to create anything other than the result (which, as you point out, has to be a new string on every invocation).

Comment: That is correct.  However, that is an optimization that is less likely than most ... because the cost-benefit analysis is not favorable.

Comment: Yes, it was more just an example of why people should be very careful when reasoning about this kind of thing. (And ultimately why it makes better sense to actually measure it in specific Java implementations instead.)

Comment: This is all very good but it's a pity that the question remains unanswered. How many strings?

Comment: @SlodgeMonster - See my other answer.  1) The question is ambiguous,  2) The answer is implementation dependent.

Comment: So the question boils down to [When are Java Strings interned?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3451145/744133) Linked SO Question is interesting because it notes the difference between 'interning' and use of the Class Constant Pool. [Java 8 Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) even states "Constant expressions of type String are always "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method String.intern". Added with this answer, it sketches a nice complete picture.

Comment: Well yes.  But the point I am making is that `x + y` in the OP's question is NOT a constant expression.  Therefore it is not implicitly interned.  In this case, the "optimization" is not permitted by the JLS.

Answer (score 12):

Take a look at decompiled class and you'll see everything :) The answer should be:

- two strings (`"xyz"` and `"abc"`) are only references to positions in constant pool so these ones are not created by your code
- one string is created directly (`new String("xyz")`)
- string concatenation is optimised by compiler and changed to StringBuilder so the last string is created indirectly

  ```
  public java.lang.String method();
  descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/String;
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC
  Code:
    stack=3, locals=3, args_size=1
   0: new           #2                  // class java/lang/String
   3: dup
   4: ldc           #3                  // String xyz
   6: invokespecial #4                  // Method java/lang/String."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   9: astore_1
  10: ldc           #5                  // String abc
  12: astore_2
  13: new           #6                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
  16: dup
  17: invokespecial #7                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
  20: aload_1
  21: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
  24: aload_2
  25: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
  28: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
  31: astore_1
  32: aload_1
  33: areturn
  ```

Comment: It's probably different from version to version of java though right?

Answer (score 9):

If you want to test for instances, run this code snippet and look at the output:

```
import static java.lang.System.identityHashCode;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String x = new String("xyz");
        String y = "abc";
        String z = x + y;

        System.out.printf("x: %d | %d\n", identityHashCode(x), identityHashCode(x.intern()));
        System.out.printf("y: %d | %d\n", identityHashCode(y), identityHashCode(y.intern()));
        System.out.printf("z: %d | %d\n", identityHashCode(z), identityHashCode(z.intern()));
    }
}
```

---

I have the following output using **jdk1.7.0_67**:

> x: 414853995 | 1719175803
>   y: 1405489012 | 1405489012
>   z: 1881191331 | 1881191331

That's a total of 4 `String` instances...

Comment: The number of instances is not the question. How many strings were **created** is the question.

Comment: *Counting String objects created by Java code* is the **title**

Comment: exactly; counting strings **created**.

Comment: Some strings are not created, they are "interned". They just exist as constants in the program. Give this a read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/java-string-pool

Comment: I don't see any flaws with my code. The program **creates** `String`s at *runtime-time* (keyword: `new`) and the compiler adds `String`s - **created** at *compile-time* - to the constant pool (`intern`)

Comment: I would never say something is *created* at compile-time. As far as I am concerned we're discussing how many string objects are dynamically allocated (at runtime).

Comment: @weston You're right, nothing is created at compile-time, but they can be created at class loading time. Does that count as part of this code or not? I wouldn't think so.

Answer (score 9):

The answer is **4**.

As you have used the `new` keyword, Java will create a new String object in normal (non pool) memory and `x` will refer to it. In addition to this, the literal "xyz" will be placed in the string pool which is again another string object.

So, the 4 string objects are:

1. "xyz" *(in non-pool memory)*
2. "xyz" *(in pool memory)*
3. "abc" *(in pool memory)*
4. "xyzabc" *(in non-pool memory)*

If your code had been like this:

```
String x = "xyz";
String y = "abc";
x = x + y;
```

then the answer would be **3**.

> Note: String #4 is in non-pool memory because String literals and the strings produced by evaluating constant expressions (see JLS §15.28) are the only strings that are implicitly interned.

*Source: SCJP Sun Certified Programmer for Java 6 (Page:434, Chapter 6)*

Comment: The same concept is also said here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881922/questions-about-javas-string-pool as mentioned by @JeroenVannevel

Comment: String #4 is not in pool memory.  See my answer.

Comment: @StephenC I didn't get you, your answer says a new String object will be created unless and until the expression is a constant expression. And String objects are created in pool memory right? So, can you clarify your point and give a reference from JLS stating the same?

Comment: @Ramswaroop - 1) A new string object is created unless the expression is a constant expression.  (According to the strict JLS definition of a constant expression.)  2)  String objects are NOT normally created in pool memory.  Only strings created by `String.intern()` go into the string pool.  (That is how the classloader creates the string objects that correspond to string literals, and string constant expressions ... for example.)

Comment: @StephenC "String objects are NOT normally created in pool memory" - Can you give a reference stating this? So far as I know it is incorrect.

Comment: The source code is the ultimate reference. Look at the source code of the String class.

Comment: @StephenC I have checked the source code and by default all string objects are **interned** unless it is created using `new` keyword. This is the only case where you actually need to invoke `intern()` method if you need the string created using `new` to be **interned**.

Comment: You missed the point.  All operations on String objects that create other String objects **except for** the `intern` method create them using `new String(....)` under the hood.  Read the source code for java.lang.String here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/String.java/.  It will confirm that fact.

Comment: String literals and strings produced by evaluating *constant expressions* (see JLS §15.28) are the only strings that are implicitly interned.

Comment: @StephenC I have emphasized this point of yours in my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I *would* say **4** because:

- [`x + y` will be replaced by the compiler with a `StringBuilder` implementation.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21724149/3453226) **+1**
- [`new` always creates a new object.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1881936/3453226) **+1**
- [Different constants are different objects.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19672578/3453226) **+2**

Here's how:

```
String x = new String("xyz"); // 2 objects created: the variable and the constant
String y = "abc"; // 1 object created: the variable
x = x + y; // 1 object created: the one by the StringBuilder class
```

Comment: Different string literals are the same object. JLS #3.10.2.

Answer (score 3):

`new String(”xyz“)` for sure creates a new instance. `"abc"` and `"xyz"` are stored in the class constant pool, `x = x + y` creates a `StringBuilder` under the hood and therefore creates a `new String`, so the count of strings are 4 here.

---

The compiler might substitute `x + y` with a constant (`"xyzabc"`), though.

Comment: I believe you can do it in 3 without violating any JLS requirements

Comment: I can, but that doesn't mean the compiler does.

Comment: *"The compiler might substitute x + y with a constant ("xyzabc"), though.
"* - Actually it is not permitted to.  Unless the expression qualifies as a compile time constant expression (and it doesn't), the concatenation is required to create a new String object

Answer (score 3):

The reason that you see different answers to the question is (in part) that it is ambiguous.

> *"How many String objects are created by the following code?"*

The ambiguity is in the phrase "created by the following code":

- Is it asking about the number of String objects that are created by (just) the execution of the code?
- Or ... is it asking about the number of String objects that need to exist during the execution of the code?

You could argue that the code implicitly creates the String objects that correspond to the literals, not when it is run, but when it is loaded.  However, those objects could be shared with other code that uses the same literals.  (And if you look hard enough, it is possible that other string objects containing the same character strings get created during the class loading process.)

---

Another reason you see different answers is that it is not entirely clear how many strings get created.  The various specifications state that new String objects *will* be created at certain points, but there is "wriggle room" on whether intermediate String objects *could* be created.

For example, the JLS states that `new` always creates a new object, and that the string concatenation operator creates a new object except under certain clearly specified cases (see my other answer).  However, the specs do not forbid creation of other strings behind the scenes.

---

But in this case, if we assume that we are using a modern Hotspot JVM, then:

- 2 string objects exist (for the string literals) before the code starts executing, and
- 2 new string objects are created (by the `new` and the `+` operator) when the code is executed.

The existence / creation of these 4 string is guaranteed by the JLS.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **4**

```
String x = new String("xyz");//First Object

String y = "abc";//Second Object

x = x + y;//Third, fourth Object
```

Comment: The `x + y` expression always generates a new String because `x` and `y` are not constant variables.

Comment: But there is a string like x,y in the string pool so the x and y refer to an other String... Java just create new strings if there is no string in the string pool

Comment: That is not what the JLS says.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sometime it's better to let byte code speak 
Examining the code using JAVAP

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=3, locals=3, args_size=1
         0: new           #16                 // class java/lang/String
         3: dup
         4: ldc           #18                 // String xyz
         6: invokespecial #20                 // Method java/lang/String."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
         9: astore_1
        10: ldc           #23                 // String abc
        12: astore_2
        13: new           #25                 // class java/lang/StringBuilder
        16: dup
        17: aload_1
        18: invokestatic  #27                 // Method java/lang/String.valueOf:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
        21: invokespecial #31                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        24: aload_2
        25: invokevirtual #32                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/St
ringBuilder;
        28: invokevirtual #36                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
        31: astore_1
        32: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 6: 0
        line 7: 10
        line 8: 13
        line 9: 32
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
               0      33     0  args   [Ljava/lang/String;
              10      23     1     x   Ljava/lang/String;
              13      20     2     y   Ljava/lang/String;
}
```

Now as seen form the code

```
At `0: new` Creates a new String Object 
At `3:dup` ; make an extra reference to the new instance

    At `4:ldc #18` as seen literal "xyz" has been placed in the pool (one string Object) 
At `6: invokespecial;` ; now call an instance initialization method with parameter and creates a object in nonpool memory.
At `9: astore_1` Stores the above reference in local variable 1(i.e x)
```

So by this time we have two String object

```
At `10:ldc #23` as seen literal "abc" has been placed in the pool (third string ) 

    At `12: astore_2` Stores the above reference in local variable (i.e y)
```

so By this time we have three String Object

```
    28: invokevirtual #36 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:
()Ljava/lang/String;;(fourth String Object is Created)
```

> So we have total of four String Object in this code.

As i'm new to programming and have started it learning only few months back point me if i went wrong somewhere and what is the correct version of it. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes.  But as is often the case with "disassembly" answers, this is not the complete picture.  It doesn't consider whether the string objects corresponding to the literals were created during class loading ... and whether they still exist at the time the code was executed.  It also doesn't consider what happens / could happen when those bytecodes are optimized.

Answer (score 1):

```
Line 1:String x = new String("xyz");
Line 2:String y = "abc";
Line 3:x = x + y;
```

Strings are Immutable so if any existing string variable need to be changed then new object will be created for assignment. Line 1,Line 2 are string objects where as Line 3 is modification of the existing string variable so new allocation need to be done to add x+y. So it should create creates 3 Objects.

Answer (score -1):

1.objects created in heap area
"xyz" //created by 'String x' and
xyzabc //created by 'x+y'(concatenation)

2.objects created in scp(string constant pool)
"xyz" //created for future purpose which is not available for garbage collection and 
"abc" //created by 'String y' literal

so total objects created in this case is 4

Answer (score -1):

The answer is 5

1. xyz in non pool memory
2. xyz in pool memory with no reference
3. abc in pool memory with reference
4. xyz still in non pool memory, reference changed to xyzabc in non pool memory
5. xyzabc in pool memory with no reference