# Can we say that the reference variable pointing to an immutable object is a constant variable?

Tags: java, string

I have a doubt from one of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29743351/8009439) in stackoverflow to the following question:

How many String objects are created by the following code?

```
String x = new String("xyz");
String y = "abc";
x = x + y;
```

In Stephen's answer he mentioned x and y are not constant variables.

My doubt- String is a final class, and it's instance will be a constant because String is an immutable class. **Why is the reference variable of this constant class not a constant variable?** - I do agree with Stephen though as `x = x + y;` points at "xyzabc" created in the heap memory.

Comment: Well, because *immutability* applies to *instances* and not *references*. You could always make your *reference* point to another *immutable object*. If you really want to prevent re-assigning of references, then make them `final`

Comment: look at this SO question may it help. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798403/string-is-immutable-what-exactly-is-the-meaning)

Comment: @TheLostMind Thanks for clearing it. So, there is no difference between the reference variable created by a constant class and a normal class?

Comment: @Pranav - There is nothing called a constant class. We only have *immutable* instances and references that can be made *constant*

Comment: @TheLostMind I meant class defined with the `final` keyword. That class will become immutable. So, nothing special will happen if I declare a variable with that immutable class name. It's the same as declaring a variable with normal class name as it's data type.

Comment: I was wrong again - Thanks to @sweeper for rightly pointing out that making a class final doesn't make the class immutable. It is said to be immutable when the value stored by the class can't be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few concepts that you need to understand.

Marking a class as `final` does not make it immutable. It just makes it un-inheritable.

> JLS §8.1.1.2
>
> A class can be declared final if its definition is complete and no subclasses are desired or required.
>
> It is a compile-time error if the name of a final class appears in the extends clause (§8.1.4) of another class declaration; this implies that a final class cannot have any subclasses.

A class is said to be immutable when the values that it stores cannot be changed after initialisation.

A constant variable is a variable marked with `final`.

> JLS §4.12.4
>
> A variable can be declared final. A final variable may only be assigned to once. Declaring a variable final can serve as useful documentation that its value will not change and can help avoid programming errors.
>
> It is a compile-time error if a final variable is assigned to unless it is definitely unassigned (§16) immediately prior to the assignment.

`x` and `y` here are not constants because they are not marked `final`. *That's it*.

"But strings can't change, so they are constants, right?" you might ask.

`String` objects themselves can't change, but string variables *can*. I'll show you:

```
String s = "Hello";
s = "Goodbye";
```

The variable's value is changed so that it refers to another string. The original string "Hello" is not changed.