# Explain both scp and heap objects creation for following code snippets

Tags: java, string

1.

```
String s1 = "Stack";  
String s2 = s1.concat(" Overflow");
```

2.

```
String s1 = "Stack";  
String s2 = s1+" Overflow";
```

Here, how many objects are created in heap and scp in both cases?

Comment: Maybe its a duplicate with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50636396/where-is-the-new-object-of-string-created-when-we-concat-using-operator) question

Comment: this is also discussed here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724072/number-of-objects-created-during-string-concatenation